Stop Long Running Spark Queries
I have lot of tables to query and extract results but some tables much time to process, I want if any particular table is taking much time, then defined time like 5 or 10 mins, I want to stop the execution for that table and move for the next table, I had tried with multiprocessing & multithreading also with cancelling spark job. It works but, in some condition, if process enters at collect method, then it hangs there working right for some.
stop the execution after timeout and move for next

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
